# Scala: How to decode a List of objects with Circe

Tags: scala, circe

My `GreedIndex` decoder is not working but I cannot seem to figure out why; I reckon it is something really silly.

I'm thinking it might be the `timeStamp` or problems with `List[CryptoData]`

```
case class CryptoData(greedValue: String, valueClassification: Sentiment, timeStamp: Long)

case class GreedIndex(name: String, data: List[CryptoData])

object GreedIndex {
  implicit val greedDecoder: Decoder[GreedIndex] = Decoder.instance { json =>

    for {
      name <- json.get[String]("name")
      data <- json.get[List[CryptoData]]("data")
    } yield GreedIndex(name, data)
  }
}

object CryptoData {

  implicit val cryptoDecoder: Decoder[CryptoData] = Decoder.instance { json =>
    val data = json.downField("data").downArray
    for {
      value               <- data.get[String]("value")
      valueClassification <- data.get[Sentiment]("value_classification")
      timestamp           <- data.get[String]("timestamp")
    } yield CryptoData(value, valueClassification, timestamp.toLong * 1000)
  }

}
```

JSON object I am trying to decode.

```
{
  "name" : "Fear and Greed Index",
  "data" : [
    {
      "value" : "53",
      "value_classification" : "Neutral",
      "timestamp" : "1631750400",
      "time_until_update" : "17264"
    },
    {
      "value" : "49",
      "value_classification" : "Neutral",
      "timestamp" : "1631664000"
    },
    {
      "value" : "30",
      "value_classification" : "Fear",
      "timestamp" : "1631577600"
    }
  ],
  "metadata" : {
    "error" : null
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a semiautomatic derivation of those decoders?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try but couldn't get it to work. I'm ideally trying to get a deeper understanding of custom codecs though.

Comment: You don't need to go down the `data` array in the `CryptoData` decoder, that is the job of the `List[x]` decoder. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/BvCAq4OFRqyf8jKH2hzFjw/4

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct because I have tried the `CryptoData` decoder by itself and it worked when there is only one object in the data array

Comment: Do you have somewhere the `Sentiment` decoder? What does it mean that it doesn't work? It doesn't compile or you have a runtime issue? If the latter then print the decoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```scala
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.deriveEnumerationDecoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder

case class CryptoData(
    greedValue: String,
    valueClassification: Sentiment,
    timeStamp: Long
)

object CryptoData {
  implicit val decoder = Decoder.forProduct3(
    "value",
    "value_classification",
    "timestamp"
  )(CryptoData.apply)
}

sealed trait Sentiment
object Sentiment {
  object Neutral extends Sentiment
  object Fear extends Sentiment

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Sentiment] = deriveEnumerationDecoder
}

case class GreedIndex(name: String, data: List[CryptoData])

object GreedIndex {
  implicit val greedDecoder: Decoder[GreedIndex] = deriveDecoder
}
```

The field names for `GreedIndex` match those in the JSON, so you can just use `deriveDecoder` in that case. For `CryptoData` this is not the case, so you need to write it manually with `forProduct3`.

Since you haven't defined `Sentiment`, I've modeled it as an enumeration. If you were to use `deriveDecoder` for this, you'd have to model it like this in the JSON: `{"Neutral": {}}`. To employ a simple String format, you need to instead use `deriveEnumerationDecoder` from the `circe-generic-extras` module.